# About skype chat history

Tags: windows-xp, data-recovery, skype

I asked skype to delete 2 weeks of chat history from just one contact and skype deleted it all from all contacts. There is no more any history saved. 
I am very frustrated because I wanted all the chat history from my other contacts. How can I recuperate it?

Answer (score -1):

Basically, you can't. But you can try to recover history files with program like [Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva).